# How do I print the keyS from a json object using JQ

Tags: json, key, jq

Sample input

```
{
 “event_timestamp”: “2016-03-16 13:19:53 UTC”,
 “query”: “Plagiarism”,
 “search_session_id”: “3605862756e95d26ac180",
 “version”: “0.0.2",
 “other”: “{\“client_timestamp\“:1458134393.932,\"ios_page_index\":3}“,
 “action”: “HIT_BOUNCE”
}

{
 “event_timestamp”: “2016-03-16 13:19:53 UTC”,
 “query”: “Plagiarism”,
 “search_session_id”: “3605862756e95d26ac180",
 “version”: “0.0.2",
 “other”:“{\“client_timestamp\“:1458134393.932,\"ios_page_index\":3,\"ios_index_path_row\":1}“,
 “action”: “HIT_BOUNCE”
}
```

I'd like to output the unique key name in "other" field

"client_timestamp,

ios_page_index,

ios_index_path_row "

Tried the following command but doesn't work so far

cat sampleexample.json | jq '.other|keys' | sort | uniq > other.json

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your input an array of objects?

Comment: nop, just a bunch of object, then in the "other" field, it's more like a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

1. The sample input is not JSON, which does not allow fancy quotes to be used as string delimiters.  The following assumes the input has been corrected.
2. The value of `.other` is a JSON string; you can use `fromjson` to change the string to a JSON object.
3. `sort|unique` is redundant, as `unique` first sorts its input.

Putting it all together:

```
$ jq  '.other | fromjson | keys_unsorted | unique' input.json
[
  "client_timestamp",
  "ios_page_index"
]
[
  "client_timestamp",
  "ios_index_path_row",
  "ios_page_index"
]
```

(Using `keys_unsorted` saves one sort operation.)

Comment: Hey, just to understand, why do you say the sample input is not a json file?